# Monte Carlo divergence

Tags: monte-carlo, divergence-operator

I'm running MonteCarlo simulations to compute the most likely voltage values in a grid.
The process is to generate a random load from a load values distribution, and simulate the load with the power flow simulation. Sometimes for some loads combination, the power flow does not converge (but still provides a value that, far from perfect is still usable)

When the MonteCarlo run goes well I get this:

[image]

However when a MonteCarlo run contains **evaluations that did not converge** I get this:
[image]

I want to understand this phenomenon better, so any insight or some reference to read further is welcome.

Comment: Is the load purely resistive, or not ?

Comment: Not in general P+Q are specified for the loads and the generation (voltage controlled) is also specified with P. The power flow is full AC power flow.